# pyQGIS Applying pseudo color ramp to an image destroyes the symbology in layers panel

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, color

I use the following code to apply pseudo color into a NDVI raster.

```
rlayer =layer = iface.activeLayer()
#stats = rlayer.dataProvider().bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.Range)
#min = stats.minimumValue
#max = stats.maximumValue
fnc = QgsColorRampShader()
fnc.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.Interpolated)
lst = [QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(-1, QColor(0,0,0)),\
       QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(-0.5, QColor(0,0,255)),\
       QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0, QColor(255,0,0)),\
       QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(0.5, QColor(0,255,255)),\
       QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(1, QColor(0,255,0))]
fnc.setColorRampItemList(lst)
shader = QgsRasterShader()
shader.setRasterShaderFunction(fnc)
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
rlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
rlayer.triggerRepaint()
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(rlayer.id())
```

The colors are applied and viewed as supposed but the legend for the raster, in layers panel, changes into 0-255 range instead of -1 to 1, as u can see in the picture.

[image: symbology range changes from -0.32 - 0.93 to 0-255]

What am I missing ?? Is there any class I should use to 'play' with the symbology ?

FYI, reading and using the stats of the raster band has no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set minimum and maximum values for "Singleband pseudocolor" renderer.

```
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(rlayer.dataProvider(), 1, shader)
renderer.setClassificationMax(1)
renderer.setClassificationMin(-1)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked ! Do you know if it is possible to display also the -0.5, 0 and 0.5 values ?

Comment: In order to display decimal values, the data type of the raster must be `float`, not `integer` or not `byte`. I noticed that fact, while looking for an answer to your question.

Comment: You can display only min and max values because it is a color ramp. If the values (-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) are discrete values then you can display them using `QgsPalettedRasterRenderer` instead of `QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer`. In that case, the legend isn't displayed as color ramp but discrete color. Please check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/454727/29431)